# Portable Class Library HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

For one of my projects I want to develop a library that can be used in different platforms (Desktop, Mobile, Surface, etc). Hence have opted Porable Class Library.

I am developing a class for calling different API calls' using HttpClient. I am stuck with how to call the method, response and work around. This is my code :-

```
    public static async Task<JObject> ExecuteGet(string uri)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // TODO - Send HTTP requests
            HttpRequestMessage reqMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
            reqMsg.Headers.Add(apiIdTag, apiIdKey);
            reqMsg.Headers.Add(apiSecretTag, ApiSecret);
            reqMsg.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/json");
            reqMsg.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

            //response = await client.SendAsync(reqMsg);
            //return response;

            //if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            //{
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return (JObject.Parse(content));
            //}
        }
    }

    // Perform AGENT LOGIN Process
    public static bool agentStatus() {
        bool loginSuccess = false;

        try
        {
            API_Utility.ExecuteGet("http://api.mintchat.com/agent/autoonline").Wait();
            // ACCESS Response, JObject ???
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
        }
```

Like ExecuteGet, I will also create for ExecutePost. My query is from ExecuteGet, if (1) I pass JObject on parsing when IsSuccessStatusCode only, then how can I know about any other errors or messages to inform the user. (2) If I pass response, then how do I assign it here

```
response = API_Utility.ExecuteGet("http://api.mintchat.com/agent/autoonline").Wait();
```

that is giving error.

What would be the best approach to handle this situation ? And I got to call multiple API's, so different API will have different result sets.

Also, can you confirm that designing this way and adding PCL reference I will be able to access in multiple projects.

UPDATE :-
As mentioned in below 2 answers I have updated my code. As mentioned in the provided link I am calling the from the other project. This is my code :-

Portable Class Library :-

```
    private static HttpRequestMessage getGetRequest(string url)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage reqMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        reqMsg.Headers.Add(apiIdTag, apiIdKey);
        reqMsg.Headers.Add(apiSecretTag, ApiSecret);
        reqMsg.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/json");
        reqMsg.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        return reqMsg;
    }

    // Perform AGENT LOGIN Process
    public static async Task<bool> agentStatus() {
        bool loginSuccess = false;
        HttpClient client = null;
        HttpRequestMessage request = null;

        try
        {
            client = new HttpClient();
            request = getGetRequest("http://api.mintchat.com/agent/autoonline");
            response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);
                bool stat = bool.Parse(o["status"].ToString());

                ///[MainAppDataObject sharedAppDataObject].authLogin.chatStatus = str;
                o = null;
            }
            loginSuccess = true;

        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            request = null;
            client = null;
            response = null;
        }

        return loginSuccess;
    }
```

From the other WPF project, in a btn click event I am calling this as follows :-

```
    private async void btnSignin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
         /// Other code goes here
         // ..........

            agent = doLogin(emailid, encPswd);
            if (agent != null)
            {
                //agent.OnlineStatus = getAgentStatus();

                // Compile Error at this line
                bool stat = await MintWinLib.Helpers.API_Utility.agentStatus();

                ...
```

I get these 4 errors :-

```
Error   1   Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' is not defined or imported D:\...\MiveChat\CSC 
Error   2   The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f89d50a3a'.   D:\...\Login Form.xaml.cs   97  21  
Error   3   Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?   D:\...\Login Form.xaml.cs   97  33  
Error   4   Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?   D:\...\Login Form.xaml.cs   47  28
```

I tried adding System.Threading.Tasks from the PCL library only, that gave 7 different errors. Where am I going wrong ? What to do to make this working ?

Please guide me on this. Have spend lots of hours figuring the best to develop a library accessible to desktop app & Win Phone app.
Any help is highly appreciative. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the result of the task, you need to use the `Result` property:

```
var obj = API_Utility.ExecuteGet("http://api.mintchat.com/agent/autoonline").Result;
```

However, it's usually not a good idea to wait synchronously for an async method to complete, because it can cause deadlocks. The better approach is to `await` the method:

```
var obj = await API_Utility.ExecuteGet("http://api.mintchat.com/agent/autoonline");
```

Note that you need to make the calling method `async` as well:

```
public static async Task<bool> agentStatus()
```

Sync and async code don't play together very well, so async tends to propagate across the whole code base.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did as you suggested. If I make agentStatus() also asnyc, then while calling from my project I will be calling as API_Utility.agentStatus(); that method wont be async , so will this work ?

Comment: @Tvd, it's the same problem, just one level up... Ideally, the code that calls `agentStatus` should also be async. If it's a void-returning method and you can't change the return type (e.g. an event handler or method override), just make it `async void` (but be sure to catch any exception that occurs, otherwise the app will crash)

Comment: you mean make methods like agentStatus async void, right ? Or make the event handler type method async void - How can I make this method async ? I really don't understand how are people using this HttpClient for accessible to multiple platforms and calling it !!! Wondering is this a good idea or will be plain full further moving ahead !!!.

Comment: @Tvd, not agentStatus; since it returns a value, it must be `async Task<bool>`. But its caller can be `async void` if it doesn't return a value; however, it's recommended to avoid `async void` when possible, and use `async Task` instead for methods that return nothing. Only use `async void` if you don't have a choice (e.g. in an event handler). Take a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Thomas, Thanks. The link cleared some issues on Async and accessing it. In one of my button click event handler I am calling this AgentStatus() using await & ConfigureAwait(false) and it works perfectly fine. After that line, I am calling another form and closing the current login form. On those lines I get runtime error - Cannot acess current thread...., The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this. NOTE async is added to btn_click event method. I believe, I get this error because the btnClick method is async and am accessing UI from it. How to handle this ?

Comment: @Tvd, if you use ConfigureAwait(false), the synchronization context is not captured, so the continuation runs on a worker thread instead of the UI thread. Don't use ConfigureAwait(false) in methods that need to access the UI after the await.

Comment: You and Yuval both have given me good guidelines to achieve what I was looking for. But to mark as answer I can select only 1 answer. For some days, I will keep toggling bet your both's answers. If I could mark both as answers I would opt that only, but can't do that. If you don't find your answer marked, please don't feel bad. I thank you from the bottom of my heart. If possible, can you try help me at this question too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454180/socketio4netclient-cannot-find-a-way-to-add-headers-to-client-c-sharp    Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you call an `async` api when making the http calls, you should also expose that async endpoint to the user, and not block the request using `Task.Wait`.

Also, when creating a third party library, it is recommanded to use [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid deadlocks when the calling code tries to access the `Result` property or the `Wait` method. You should also follow guidelines and mark any async method with `Async`, so the method should be called `ExecuteStatusAsync`

```
public static Task<bool> AgentStatusAsync() 
{
    bool loginSuccess = false;

    try
    {
        // awaiting the task will unwrap it and return the JObject
        var jObject = await API_Utility.ExecuteGet("http://api.mintchat.com/agent/autoonline").ConfigureAwait(false);

    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

And inside `ExecuteGet`:

```
response = await client.SendAsync(reqMsg).ConfigureAwait(false);
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In case `IsSuccessStatusCode` is false, you may throw an exception to the calling code to show something went wrong. To do that, you can use the `HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode` which throws an exception if the status code != 200 OK.

Personally, if `ExecuteGet` is a public API method i would definitely not expose it as a `JObject` but a strongly typed type.

Comment: ExecuteGet will be just a method to be called internally by other methods of the class to execute et or Post API calls. The parsing of return value or creating data to send will be done by other public methods like AgentStatus. And from other project, this library's AgentStatus() will be called. This is how I am planning to design. Honestly, I am doing this just to avoid writing the same code twice for Win Desktop & win Phone app and making sure that it works on all platforms. This all what I am planning and thinking is that right - I mean am I in right direction !!

Comment: If `ExecuteGet` is internal, then you can discard my comment about returning a strong type, all else stands. Moreover, if all your request (get, post, put etc) return the same response type, you can unify the `ExecuteMethod` to one which accepts a string and a method type

Comment: unifying a single method for all Get calls and just parsing in other method was my motto. Well, I got little hands on that, but now am stuck on calling AgentStatus() thru my GUI project. I have updated my code above, can you please have a look at it and help me if you can. Thanks Yuval. Can you show me calling an async method (AgentStatus) that passes some return (Task<bool>) value and an async method that returns just Task in place of void thru my GUI app.

Comment: As for your second error, try installing http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

Comment: Thanks Yuval, adding Microsoft.Bcl.Async to GUI ptoject solved all errors. In one of my button click event handler I am calling this AgentStatus() using await & ConfigureAwait(false) and it works perfectly fine. After that line, I am calling another form and closing the current login form. On those lines I get runtime error - Cannot acess current thread...., The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.  NOTE async is added to btn_click event method. I believe, I get this error because the btnClick method is async and am accessing UI from it. How to handle this ?

Comment: When calling `agentStatus` dont use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on it as it will continue executing on a threadpool thread. Simply `await agentStatus()`

Comment: You and Thomas both have given me good guidelines to achieve what I was looking for. But to mark as answer I can select only 1 answer. For some days, I will keep toggling bet your both's answers. If I could mark both as answers I would opt that only, but can't do that. If you don't find your answer marked, please don't feel bad. I thank you from the bottom of my heart. If possible, can you try help me at this question too - stackoverflow.com/questions/24454180/… Thanks.